# Regex to match if a specific string between curly braces

Tags: regex, kotlin

I have css as a String such as the following

```
    .c8450 {
    color: #000000; font-family: TsukuMin,TsukuMin,TsukuMin,TsukuMin; font-size: 18px; line-height: 1.6em;
    }
    .c8451 {
    text-indent: -4em; text-align: left; min-width: 1.6em; border-top: solid transparent 4em;
    }
.c8451 {
    text-indent: -4em; text-align: left; min-width: 1.6em; border-top: solid transparent 4em; text-align-last:auto;
    }
```

And I need to find a match between two curly braces if it contains a text-align property but not a text-align-last property, so I should be able to match the 2nd set of curly braces so that it returns

```
{text-indent: -4em; text-align: left; min-width: 1.6em; border-top: solid transparent 4em;}
```

I can find the matches between the curly braces with `\{+([^}]+)}+` and find the text-indent property with `text-align:(.*);` and  but I'm unsure of how to combine the two to match this specific condition.

Comment: You should be using a CSS parser here, rather than pure regex.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
fun main() {
    val text = """
        .c8450 {
            color: #000000; font-family: TsukuMin,TsukuMin,TsukuMin,TsukuMin; font-size: 18px; line-height: 1.6em;
        }
        .c8451 {
            text-indent: -4em; text-align: left; min-width: 1.6em; border-top: solid transparent 4em;
        }
        .c8451 {
            text-indent: -4em; text-align: left; min-width: 1.6em; border-top: solid transparent 4em; text-align-last:auto;
        }
    """
    val pattern = "\\{(.|\\r?\\n)*?\\}".toRegex()
    val matches = pattern.findAll(text)
    val list: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
    matches.forEach { f ->
        val value = f.value
        val pe = "text-align".toRegex();
        val pne = "text-align-last".toRegex()
        
        if(pe.containsMatchIn(value) && !pne.containsMatchIn(value)){
            list.add(value)
        }
    }
    
    print(list)
}
```

**output**

```
[{
        text-indent: -4em; text-align: left; min-width: 1.6em; border-top: solid transparent 4em;
}]
```